# ODP.NET Buffer overflow when connection pooling enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, connection-pooling, odp.net

Enabled connection pooling on a .NET Web application, now staff run into the following error at random stages of the application.

> Error:Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 32 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT"

We disabled pooling and the problem immediately stopped.

1. Any clues as to why we would hit the buffer overflow issue only whilst connection pooling enabled?
2. Are there any gotchas we need to be aware of using connection pooling?

I've read the ODP documentation and can't see anything obvious, but seen other forum comments suggesting not to use global variables with connection pools.

I don't believe setting the buffer size to 1,000,000 in various functions is the real fix and i'm concerned that whatever causing this might have a greater impact on other processes.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: ODP.NET is a free to use library, but it is not opensource. You are describing what is likely a bug that only Oracle could fix (it is the library they provided). I would suggest trying the latest ODP.NET library and cross fingers.

Comment: Thanks - We are unfortunately already on the latest ODP client.

Comment: `"SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT"` you must executing some stored proc where you have this `dbms_ourput.Put_line`. Try commenting this out

Comment: Keep in mind, in conn. pooling you are using 1 real connection and bunch of "logical connections"

Comment: @T.S. can you elaborate "1 real connection and a bunch of logical connections" please?

We are using DBMS_OUTPUT, but no single function or process ever hit this limit without connection pooling, so why would this be occurring now?

Comment: If you read oracle docs, it explains conn pooling, If pooling is set, you use 1 physical connection. All others are - logical. i.e. they just pointers to that 1 physical connection. It probably means that `DBMS_OUTPUT` buffer is shared for all your calls. When you don't have pooling, you have multiple physical connections and each has such buffer.

Comment: @T.S. Thanks - This makes sense, however, I can't find the Oracle docs proving logical/physical connections nor that the buffer is shared per connection but this would explain why its happening, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Oracle has a lot of sources for java developers. You can dig more info there on how it works  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/connpoca.htm#1057365